Data editing, directly in the database or WFS-T?
We are starting the process of interoperability of geospatial data, using geOrchestra, which allows the administration of GeoServer and GeoNetwork in a unified way, in addition to offering more services.
And, we have a question about making layers available for editing by our internal customers. The question is: about how to make the layers available for editing, updating or deleting, would it be directly in the database or via WFS-T? How are they used in corporate or institutional environments?
Knowing which method is most used and which would be safer when dealing with information security

Weight the pros and cons of both options and make a choice. There is no single nor best way of doing this.

plus make sure your taking nightly snapshots (database) - for worse case you only lose a day of changes. preferably one that is offsite. rather than losing the entire database.
